# Android P incoming call number can't be fetched without CALL_LOG permission

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, android-9.0-pie

Android P incoming call number can't be fetched without CALL_LOG permission and google is not allowing CALL_LOG permission. How can I fetch the incoming number on Android P?

```
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
    this.context = context;
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telephony.listen(new PhoneStateListener(){
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *google is not allowing CALL_LOG permission*?

Comment: For SMS/CALL_LOG Permission you need to request google to allow this permission for your app and they are not allowing in my case. For more info: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303

Comment: There is no way to do this anymore. Either you need google approval or get your app signed by the telecom operator.

Comment: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9214102 say Google might approve if you state your case well.